# Maven plugin- exclude log4j1 transitive dependency

Tags: maven

I have created sample application which has only one plugin 'aspectj-maven-plugin'.
When I build application, log4j1.2.12 is getting downloaded by this plugin.
Is there any way to avoid downloading log4j1 from maven plugin ?

I tried different options, like- exclude from dependency, increase plugin version, exclude from maven plugin, etc., but no luck.
My pom.xml -

```
<properties>
<aspectj.version>1.8.10</aspectj.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>          
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
    </dependency>       
</dependencies>
    
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.10</version>
        <configuration>
            <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>                    
        </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>      
                <goal>test-compile</goal> 
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

I have observed same with my another multi-module application. I have different maven plugin in different module- 'maven-war-plugin', 'maven bundle-plugin', etc.
One or another plugin is downloading log4j1.
If I increase version of one plugin then dependency is getting downloaded with another plugin.
I tried many options but no luck.

Log4j1 is not getting bundled in my war but what I need is log4j1 should not be downloaded.

Please let me know if there is any option to exclude lo4j1 from maven plugin.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to exclude it? Having log4j in a Maven plugin is hardly a security concern.

Comment: Thanks Fabian. As this point (due to some requirement), Is there any way to exclude ?

Comment: I really don't like if people want to do something and refuse to explain why. Often, if someone explains why, one can find a better solution for the original problem. That said, you can try to add exclusions for log4j to all Maven plugins, and also add dependencies on log4j version 2 and the relevant JARs and hope it might work. But I think this is the wrong way.

Comment: I tired that as well. I added exclude with plugin- `<plugin> <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.10</version>
<configuration>
 <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
 <source>1.8</source>
 <target>1.8</target>
 <excludes><exclude>
 <groupId>log4j</groupId>
 <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
 </exclude>
</excludes>     
</configuration>
<executions>
<execution>
<goals>
<goal>compile</goal>     
<goal>test-compile</goal>
</execution></executions> </plugin>`  and also added log4j2 dependency. But, no luck.

Comment: If this should work at all, you need to use the `<dependencies>` tag inside your plugin like https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Using_the_dependencies_Tag

Comment: It's still not working. I increased aspectj version also to 1.14.0. Then after log4j1 is getting downloaded with 'maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile)'.  This maven-compiler is not there in my pom.xml.  If I add maven-compiler in pom.xml then also it downloading log4j1.  Any idea ? My changes are in next comment-

Comment: `<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId><artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin </artifactId><version>1.14.0</version><configuration> ... <artifactSet><excludes><exclude>log4j:log4j</exclude></excludes></artifactSet></configuration><dependencies> <dependency><groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId><artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId><version>2.17.1</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId><artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId><version>2.17.1</version></dependency></dependencies><executions><execution><goals><goal>compile</goal><goal>test-compile</goal>
... </plugin>`

Comment: Again: Could you explain why you are so keen on removing log4j? You will probably break your build and spend days repairing it. If we know your reasons, maybe we can find a better approach.

Comment: Due to Log4j1 vulnerability issue, we are migrating to Log4j2. All application changes are done but log4j1 is still getting downloaded by some maven plugin. I understand it will not be bundled with application or it may not create any other issue. But, we have requirement that it should not be downloaded at all.  Thanks

Comment: The exclusions should go to the `<dependency>`  you exclude them from. The should not be part of the `<configuration>`.

Comment: I tried that as well but it's not working. Is there any  example which i can refer please. I tried different options, one of them is- `<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId><artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId><version>2.17.1</version><exclusions><exclusion><groupId>log4j</groupId><artifactId>log4j</artifactId></exclusion>`.      I added same exclusion with log4j-core as well. But, after these changes log4j1 is getting downloaded with another plugin 'maven-compiler-plugin' which is not there anywhere in my application. So, one or another plugin is downloading log4j1.

Comment: It maybe the case that you need to write 20 or 30 of such exclusions if you want to eliminate it from every dependency of every plugin. You also need to explicitly add the default plugins like the compiler-plugin to your POM. As I said: Expect it to be several days of work.

Comment: I tried but no luck. I just increased version of maven-compiler-plugin. Now,  It's downloading with main plugin aspectj-maven-plugin which already have exclusion. Doesn't seems quick/easy fix.

Comment: If I were you, I would talk to the person who defined that requirement (your manager) and make clear, that this a tedious and maybe impossible task, and that you do not really gain much from this. Requirements are not set in stone.